# How to register a daughter

Tags: citizenship, uk-citizens, usa

I am a married British citizen living in the U.S. How do I register and get a British passport for my daughter born in the U.S. Prior to 2000?

Comment: Are you a British citizen "by descent" (i.e. you were born outside the UK and got citizenship at birth from your parents), or "otherwise than by descent" (any other way, including if you were born in the UK or naturalized in the UK)?

Comment: Also, are you the mother or father? And if father, was your daughter born in wedlock?

Answer (score 4):

Your daughter is [probably already a British citizen](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen/y/on-or-after-1-january-1983/no/yes). If this is the case, then she can [Apply online for a UK passport](https://www.gov.uk/apply-renew-passport). Otherwise, she can try to register as a UK citizen and then apply for a passport.